# Can I use rubber bumper pads to prop open a door?

Tags: doors

I live in a one person apartment. Since no one else lives there, I don't need the door to my bedroom to close. Actually, I would prefer if it could be permanently propped open. The reason is, if I have my hands full, I can open the door without moving my hands. Or if I'm carrying a glass of water, I can always have 2 hands on the glass and open the door with my back. This is impossible if the door is latched. I would like to stop the door just before it latches.

I searched on Google Images and found these rubber bumper pads. They're clear and practically invisible. I was thinking I would place a few of them on the sides and they would make sure the door doesn't shut. I think they're from 3M, which I have used their products to hang wall art. Those products worked like a charm. My pictures to this day stand up.

I think this is the solution to this problem, but I would like to confirm with the experts on this website. There shouldn't be a problem with applying these rubber pads to the side of my bedroom door, right?

Insight is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds more like a case for a doorstop -- either wedge style, or flip-down, or (what's becoming my personal favorite) magnetic -- to hold the door open rather than arguing with the latch. And that would leave you with the option of closing the door if you ever have houseguests or other reasons to do so.

Answer (score 3):

When I was growing up, we just stuffed whatever we could find (paper, plastic, etc) into the latch hole to fill it up.  That would probably work for you.

I didn't come up with the stuff to keep the door from latching, and I didn't make it better. <-- Lame 3M joke.

Comment: +1 for the lame 3M joke. I was going to suggest tape myself.

Comment: +1 for just preventing it from latching.  In the event of a night time fire elsewhere, a closed bedroom door will slow the spread of smoke increasing the amount of time before the air in the room becomes unbreathable.

Answer (score 1):

A piece of tape over the latch hole, or the latch itself would prevent the latch from catching.  You could also remove the latch from the door, and replace it when you move out.